# Proper declaration of constants in NodeJS to prevent memory leaks and caching properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, memory-leaks, constants

I was wondering do to a conversation with a teammate, where should you declare constant variables.
I have a couple of variables declared in a function that set a `const` variable with the info retrieved from a JSON config file.
So the question is if that variable should be declared at the top of the file so it can be created at the first run of the application or it's fine to keep it in the function because it's going to be destroyed after the request its ended.
This it's for a web API application, so part of my question is how that NodeJs manages the memory and what it should be a better practice for declaring constants that will hold a template path, for example.
And the second question is if using new() when declaring a `const` variable from a `require(..)` can cause memory leak at some point, and what should be a good practice.
I added an example, I hope that clear up whats I'm asking here. I'm kind of new with Node and I would like to code has proper as possible.
Thanks!.

```
// library that read variables on a json
const config = require('config');

// talking about declaration of constants it's it better to 
// create the at the top of the file or just where ever it's needed
// does it load once and stays in memory for all coming request 
// or it's destroy every time the request ends.

const templatePath = config.get('sendgrid.template');

// can this type of declaration cause memory leaks
const instance = require('/moduleOne').new();

function readContent() {

    // IS IT BETTER TO HAVE IT HERE 
    let path = config.get('server.template');
}

module.exports = templateSender;
```

Comment: It's only a memory leak if the memory usage *grows*. Instantiating a constant in a module *once* can by definition not lead to a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

As you may see from this example
https://repl.it/@AlieksandrAlie7/nodejs-playground

Side effects applied only once during first require. So it is hard to declare constants in such a way to have memory leaks.

Also, I do not think that it is a good idea to write code in terms of performance without any profiling. First, you need to write good quality code, then make profiling to troubleshoot perf and memory problems.

Lift up parts of your code (consts and funcs) and decompose if necessary.

Also, it is better to avoid side-effects during require. Cause it is hard to reason about such side-effects and leads less to maintainable code.